# Gem dependencies in Rails Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-engines

I have followed the [Getting Started with Engines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) in Rails documentation and I have set up an `api` engine in `engines` directory. According to the paragraph [6.6 Other Gem Dependencies](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#other-gem-dependencies) one is supposed to define the gem dependencies in `engines/my_api/my_api.gemspec` file and that is pretty much what I did:

```
s.add_dependency "responders", "2.0"
```

After adding

```
`gem 'my_api', path: "engines/my_api"`
```

to the applications `Gemfile` and running bundler, everything looks as expected:

```
 bundle install | grep responders
 Installing responders 2.0.0
```

In the next step I set up a root path with a corresponding controller etc. and go to `engines/my_api/app/controllers/my_api/application_controller.rb` and add following content:

```
module MyApi
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    respond_to :json
  end
end
```

I start the rails server, go the root url and guess what? I get following message:

**The controller-level respond_to' feature has been extracted to the responders gem. Add it to your Gemfile to continue using this feature: gem 'responders', '~> 2.0' Consult the Rails upgrade guide for details.**

As suggested in the error message, I've added the gem to the applications `Gemfile`, run `bundle install` and everything works as expected.

As far as I understood, engines are supposed to be self contained rails apps. From a self contained app I would at least expect to correctly resolve its dependencies. I assume that I am just doing something wrong and I hope someone will be able to help me to tackle down the problem, why do I have to explicitly specify the gem in the applications `Gemfile`?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention the versions:

```
$ gem list | grep rails
coffee-rails (4.1.0)
jquery-rails (4.0.3)
rails (4.2.1)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
sass-rails (5.0.3)
sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
```

Comment: Engines use namespacing to isolate the engine code from the main app. You may want to try adding the responders gem to your main app too.

Comment: That's what I did, but doesn't it defeat the purpose of an engine? What, if my engine depends no 20 gems? It would be a nightmare to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you observe, the gem is included in your bundle whether it is in your application's Gemfile or not. The difference is that when `Bundler.require` is called during application initialisation it only auto requires the gem's in your application's Gemfile - not indirect dependencies.

If your gem requires the responders gem gem to be loaded then it should require it explicitly - for example at the top of my_api.rb